# Iterating over 2 dimensional python list to insert every cell's x and y coordinates

Tags: python, matrix, coordinates

I want to create a grid containing a pair of coordinates of the cell in question as such:

```
grid = [
[[0,0],[0,1]],
[[1,0],[1,1]],
[[2,0],[2,1]]
]
```

And so on.
When I do the following:

```
colRange = 2
rowRange = 3
for column in range(colRange):
   for row in range(rowRange):
       grid[row][column] = [row,column]
```

I expected to get the outcome of above, but instead I receive this:

```
grid = [
[[2,0],[2,1]],
[[2,0],[2,1]],
[[2,0],[2,1]]
]
```

and so on. So it inputs the maximum row index into the first coordinate, for every row and column.

I would love if someone could explain what is happening here.

Comment: as a set of 0's: [[0]*rowCount]*colCount
Am now realizing that the initalizing as such is kind of redundant with list comprehension being a thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
grid = [[[i,j] for j in range(colRange)] for i in range(rowRange)]

>>> grid
[[[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]]]
```